# Find Missing value between 2 arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to find the missing values between 2 arrays...

```
$in_id  = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
$out_id = array(0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
```

in 2nd variable $out_id missing values 2, 4, 12 I want these values...

**Result: e.g**

```
$missing_values = 2,4,12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php),

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_diff()` for getting difference in array

```
<?php

$in_id  = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
$out_id = array(0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
print_r(array_diff($in_id, $out_id))
?>

Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [4] => 4
    [12] => 12
)
```